# Flutter: MaterialPageRoute The builder for route "/" returned null

Tags: flutter, mobile

I just start learning flutter and decided to follow a tutorial. The video says that I have to use MaterialPageRoute in Route factory, and declare global consts for my routes, yet I got this error

```
    The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dirty):
The builder for route "/" returned null.
```

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:layout_in_flutter/screens/location_detail/location_detail.dart';
import 'screens/locations/locations.dart';
import 'style.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

const LocationsRoute = '/';
const LocationDetailRoute = '/location_detail';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: _routes(),
      theme: _theme(),
    );
  }

  RouteFactory _routes() {
    return (settings) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> arguments = settings.arguments;
      Widget screen;
      switch (settings.name) {
        case LocationsRoute:
          screen = Locations();
          break;
        case LocationDetailRoute:
          screen = LocationDetail(arguments['id']);
          break;
        default:
          return null;
      }
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => screen);
    };
  }

  ThemeData _theme() {
    return ThemeData(
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline6: AppBarTextStyle,
        ),
      ),
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        headline6: Headline6TextStyle,
        bodyText2: BodyText2Style,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: any idea what do I do to solve that?

Comment: post first 6-8 top frames from the stacktrace

Comment: MaterialApp
lib\main.dart:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      MaterialRouteTransitionMixin.buildPage.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/material/page.dart:111
#1      MaterialRouteTransitionMixin.buildPage
package:flutter/…/material/page.dart:117
#2      _ModalScopeState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/routes.dart:820
#3      Builder.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/basic.dart:7183
#4      StatelessElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4701
...

Comment: I did add that on the script

Comment: never mind, found out already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, god, now I am so embarrassed
the problem is caused as I put the whole code on the main.dart, when I separate the whole code to another new file, it works. Thank you